# How to fetch all the recurring events based on series master event

Tags: google-calendar-api, outlook-calendar

How can we get all the recurring events occurrences based on the series master event, from the Outlook Calendar API. We have similar kind of API in Google Calendar API, [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances) is the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#get-event-instances) is the API link and is working fine